# SQL Join on match against every record

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Good Morning Everyone,
I am hoping that someone can help me with a problem.  I am trying to figure out how to find which employees work on every project.

If I have a table of works_on with column ssn, project_id, and hours worked; and a table projects with project_id, project_name, dept.  I need to know which employee(s) work on every project.

It is a homework problem and I am supposed to do it with relational algebra, but plain old sql code or any ideas on how to do this is general would be appreciated.  I just don't see it...

Thanks for any pointers.

EDIT: Here is my final version, if anyone has any comments/suggestions.  I think I got it.  Also, it joins with the employee table to get the name, as that is required in the homework specifications.

```
WORKS1 ← ρ (SSN, PNUMBER) π ESSN, PNO (WORKS_ON)
WORKS_DIV ← (PROJECT x WORKS1) – WORKS1
EMP_EVERY_PROJ ← WORKS1 – WORKS_DIV 
π FNAME, MINIT, LNAME (EMP_EVERY_PROJ ⋈ SSN=SSN EMPLOYEE)
```

Comment: To steer you the right direction, the typical way to approach this is to use a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING COUNT(distinct project_id)` filter

Comment: You can also search the [`[sql-match-all]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-match-all) tagged questions.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~mccann/research/divpresentation.pdf) is an article that explains division uses algebra and SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which employees work on every project

That's a nasty problem called [relational division](https://www.google.com/search?q=relational%20division).  Here's an [article with some solutions](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I think I can figure it out from here.  Thanks!

Comment: So does this look about right?

WORKS1 ← ρ (SSN, PNUMBER) π ESSN, PNO (WORKS_ON)
WORKS_DIV ← (PROJECT x WORKS1) – WORKS1
WORKS1 – WORKS_DIV

Comment: @Kevin: It's generally preferable to add complex follow up information to your question (not in comments), where you can format it properly.

Comment: If `works1` is the projects an employee is working on; and `works_div` the projects an employee is not working on; then someone who is in `works1` but not in `works_div` is working on all projects.  Could be right but not sure :)

Comment: @Andomar thanks for your help, I think that based on what you said, I got it right.

I added the solution to the main question, formated.